# longtable + multicol: How to simulate \endhead using texts at fixed positions on each page?

Tags: spacing, longtable, multicol

I'm using the problematic combination of packages `longtable` and `multicol`, but so far after two runs I had perfect results. There is only one thing that doesn't work: repeating column titles on each page for each column from the `multicol` package (I have 2 columns).
Without `multicol` the following extra code achieves my result:

```latex
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Page}}\\
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Page}}\\
\endhead
```

But with `multicol` it doesn't work (that's probably expected).
As a workaround, I would like to place the text `Page` at a fixed position on each page at the top to simulate the result. But I don't know how to tell "do this before the table starts on each page and as long the table has not ended".

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    left=1.5cm,
    right=1.5cm,
    top=1.5cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}


\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\newenvironment{fakelongtable}
        {\setbox\ltmcbox\vbox\bgroup
        \csname @twocolumnfalse\endcsname
        \csname col@number\endcsname\csname @ne\endcsname}
        {\unskip\unpenalty\unpenalty\egroup\unvbox\ltmcbox}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.85}
    \begin{fakelongtable}
        \begin{longtable}{b{4.4cm}r}
            \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Page}}\\
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{2}{r}{{Page}}\\%This line and the folowing has no effect using multicol; probably expected.
            \endhead
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text Text\nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
            \hangindent=1em Text Text Text Text \nolinebreak\dotfill & 1 \\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{fakelongtable}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: basically you can't you should probably use supertable or xtab por something that breaks the pages by hand. both longtable and multicol are designed around the idea of using a standard tex page breaker output routine that asynchronously breaks thngs up after all typesetting done so you can not add text during  typesetting that tests if it will be at the top of the page or column.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried the named packages, but none of them gave me the exact result like I have now. I thought that I know for sure the page number before and after the problematic environment. So at least in a second run I could overwrite with tikz or so at fixed positions for all pages between x and y.

Comment: if you want to really use the page (rather than table) head you can use a custom page style of course but then you'd probably want to use fixed width columns in the table so you knew where to add the text

Comment: Thanks, I think that can make it work! I can set before the environment and unset again after the environment the pagestyle!

Comment: I would accept this as an answer, also without example code, I think it's a good idea as workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't. You could probably use `supertable` or `xtab` or something that breaks the pages by hand. Both `longtable` and `multicol` are designed around the idea of using a standard tex page breaker output routine that asynchronously breaks thngs up after all typesetting done so you can not add text during typesetting that tests if it will be at the top of the page or column.

You could however use the page (rather than table) head: you can use a custom page style, but then you'd probably want to use fixed width columns in the table so you knew where to add the text. This also assumes that you always start the table at a new page.